# Converting Websites in HTML/XML into RDF

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

I want to convert the data on any html website to rdf.
do you know any html to rdf converter?
or, do you recommend for this purpose the use of XQuery or GRDDL?

Comment: Is this called "Semantic Markup"? I think no automatic tool available. I know a tool named SMORE (was introduced in "Introduction to the Semantic Web and Semantic Web Services" written by Liyang Yu). Have a try :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, an automatic conversion is not possible, since HTML says what something looks like, and not what it means. If the HTML contains existing markup, you could use Anything2Triples (http://developers.any23.org/) to get RDF out.

If it's just HTML you have to write your own extraction rules somehow. GRDDL would work, but I would probably simply use python + BeautifulSoup. It depends what technology/language you know already!

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML contains embedded [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/) the you can use an RDFa parser to extract the information.  There are parsers available for various platforms and languages so depends on your development environment.